# Escaping a parenthesis in Powershell's -Replace parameter not working

Tags: powershell, recursion, file-rename

I want to rename this file:

`Howard -((TV) )RED HEADED LEAGUE.mp4`

To this:

`Howard - (TV) RED HEADED LEAGUE.mp4`

Because the -Replace Powershell command expects regex regular expressions, I did this to rename the files:

`Get-ChildItem | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace '\(\(TV\) \)',' \(TV\) '}`

But, outputs this error:

`Cannot rename the specified target, because it represents a path or device name.`

And escaping the parenthesis with back ticks, as google suggests, outputs no errors but no files are renamed:

`` Get-ChildItem | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace '`(`(TV`) `)',' `(TV`) '} ``

How can I make this work? Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to escape the substitution string: `-replace '\(\(TV\) \)',' (TV) '`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Awesome! That works. I didn't realize the substitution string is not a regular expression. (facepalm) Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the substitution string (second right-hand side argument to `-replace`) does NOT need escaping!

The substitute placed in the string verbatim, so the resulting file name in your example becomes `Howard - \(TV\) RED HEADED LEAGUE.mp4` - which is why the file system complains, `\` is not a valid file name character.

If you simply do:

```
{$_.Name -replace '\(\(TV\) \)',' (TV) '}
```

... it'll work :)